# What was a DEC PDP-11/85 intended to be, and why might it be able to use DECsystem-10 software?

Tags: history, pdp-11, dec

In this DEC [PDP-11 Strategy Memo](http://bitsavers.org/pdf/dec/pdp11/memos/740919_PDP-11_Strategy_Status.pdf) from Sept 1974, there is this curious question.

> HOW MUCH OF THE DEC SYSTEM 10 SOFTWARE
> CAN THE 11/85 USE, OR DOES THE 11/85 HAVE
> TO START FROM SCRATCH?
>
> CONFLICTING GOALS?

(All caps in original)

What was the PDP-11/85 intended to be?
Why might it be able to run DECsystem-10 software?

To put this in context, the VAX strategy was still emerging at the time; there was still thought that a VAX really would be an addressability extension of the PDP-11.  The same memo talks about extended (i.e., 32-bit) addressing in the 11/44, which did not happen.

Even if the 11/85 was an early designation for what became the VAX-11/780, why might it be able to use DECsystem-10 software?  Were they talking about BLISS source compatibility? Or something more fundaemental?

Or, to summarize: what was a PDP-11/85 expected to be?

*Edited to add:* so far I've failed to find any mention other than the one that sparked this question.

Comment: The DEC-10 was my favorite computer, and TOPS-10 was pretty stable and mature by then.  I can't imagine the 11/85 actually running 10 instructions.  Maybe they were talking about fitting the major building blocks together more or less the same way.

Comment: Agreed, DEC-10 was quite nice in many ways.  I can think of little compatibility at hardware level with PDP11/85 but possibly some source code compatibility might have existed.  Page 4 of the memo asks more generally about the relationship between 11/85 and DEC10,20.  I’d read from this that the answer to the code compatibility question is ‘not much’.

Comment: I never moved ahead from the DEC-10 to the PDP-11.  As a consequence, when I had to get on a VAX, I went from operating system guru to poor dumb jerk who doesn't know how to do anything but login and logout.  But that was at the surface level.  At a deeper level, VAX and DEC-10 really came out of the same culture.

Comment: @Frog - agree on 'not much', but why would anyone even imagine that this -11 could be different to all previous -11s in that respect?

Comment: Good question, also why a 16/32 bit processor should have any code compatibility with a 36 bit machine.  I don’t know anything about Robert Frith’s credentials (author of the memo) but you’d expect them to know better.  Perhaps it’s just a request for clarification so they have in writing that there’s zero code compatibility.

Comment: My wild guess would be that there was some hope that the "new architecture" would somehow bridge the gap between the -11 and -10 lines; certainly the corporate strategy became "all our eggs in the VAX basket".

Comment: Have you read through all the memos in the archive where this one is? The strategies were apparently already set when this meeting was held, so an earlier meeting memo might shed some light.

Comment: I did, at the time I first posted this question. Maybe I'll revisit them. But one part of the strategy was to extend the address space of the PDP-11 (which of course became a whole new architecture); maybe the question of what to do with the 36-bitters was still in play at the time.

Comment: The memo named '740613_PDP-11_Strategy.pdf' (http://bitsavers.org/pdf/dec/pdp11/memos/740613_PDP-11_Strategy.pdf) says about 11/85: "See users desires. Is that what we are building? If so, users are happy." From that my guess is that the 11/85 was made for one or more companies that already for a long time were using PDP-10. They had made a (big ?) part of the specification and also had a large assortment of PP-10 software they wished to continue to use.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there never was an 11/85, though. There would have been signs in the 11M kernel code if it existed, and I was a keen student of that.  (There was an 11/44 but I'm not convinced it's the machine described there - machine designators used in planning were not necessarily carried through to release.  The 11/55 described might well be the 11/55 that shipped: 11/70 CPU, no cache, bipolar memory).

Comment: *Disciplined* use of BLISS would be able to produce source compatibility, but this might well take more care than was routinely used. BLISS-16 (PDP-11), BLISS-32 (VAX) and BLISS-36 (PDP-10) are described as different dialects of the language in the 1987 version of the BLISS reference manual. The memory addressing was very different: a PDP-10 was a 36-bit word-addressed machine, which packed five 7-bit characters per word. Any kind of PDP-11 successor is going to be a byte-addressed machine with one character per 8-bit byte; that description applies to both PDP-11 and VAX.

Comment: I was a BLISS-32 and to a lesser extent a BLISS-16 programmer, but always for a specific architecture. I almost certainly assumed byte-addressable memory. At the time of the 11/85 memo, BLISS-10 and BLISS-11 were the extant versions. I have no personal experience of those, I suspect commonality was harder if not impossible.